# Tracking payments between users?

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I am creating a website allow users to sell their things on my website using Paypal. However, I don't know how to securely check if the payment between them is successful or cancelled.

My scenario is:

> User1 --- sell ---> Item #1234 --- to ---> User2

User1 selling item #1234 on his page on my website. User2 go to the page and click on *Pay by Paypal*.

I know I can provide two URLs for successful payment and cancelled payment but how do I securely check if the payment is actually successful or cancelled inside the URL, and detect fake requests (sent using curl for example)?

I have researched on both IPN and PDT but they require User1 to setup his account but for that, also all his transactions will send notification to my URL which is not acceptable by users.

Also I do not want to receive all payments for all users.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be better off doing is having User2 pay YOU for the item, and then when you receive the payment (by IPN) you then forward the payment to User1.

Even better may be to have a virtual currency for your site, so users can buy currency, buy/sell items with that currency, then withdraw that currency to their PayPal.

Comment: Wouldn't you lose money due to transaction fees on paypal though?